# How to use DialogBox in Windows API

Tags: winapi, dialog

I'm learning windows api for some weeks, now I got a problem, my code is like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
switch(message){
  case(...)
    DialogBox(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG),hwnd,(DLGPROC)MyDialogProc);
    return 0;
}

bool MyDialogProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (message){
      ...       
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't know what else should I do before I use `DialogBox` where should I place `EndDialog()`. `IDD_MYDIALOG` is a resource file created by myself. I don't understand what is `hInstance` and how to get it, I think I just need a simple example, than I can know how use `DialogBox`. Thank you for helping!

Comment: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/dialogs.html

Comment: While you're at it, fix the declaration of your dialog procedure or it won't work right. You'll know you declared it right when it compiles without requiring a (DLGPROC) cast.

Comment: Open up your copy of Petzold and use that to supply examples. No point re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the website given by Xearinox helps me a lot, Raymond Chen and David Heffernan, thank you for your help.